# Is it possible to split a grid item to allow different spans?

Tags: css, html, grid-layout, css-grid

I have an article and an aside (sidebar) element - easy, except the title and sub-heading of the article need to span the entire row.  If I take the title/sub-heading out of the article, the article element is no longer semantically complete.

Is there a way, using CSS Grid, to have the format below, where Title, Sub and Content are all a part of an "Article" element, and "Aside" is the second in a 2 column grid?

From my research so far, it seems this is *not* possible.

[image: Example of desired grid layout]

Comment: can u give an images for the example of the result ?

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo - sure, see update.

Comment: yes, there is a way, but what is your current html and css code that you've done so far? do you using any css framework such as bootstrap or creating this without any framework?

Comment: I'm trying to create this using CSS Grid - no Bootstrap or framework

Answer (score 2):

You can *hack* your way through using *nested CSS grid* if you know:

1. The `width` of the *aside* section
2. The `height` of the *title* and *sub heading* sections

(in many layouts, these dimensions are fixed)

You can use a *pseudo* element that create a *space* for the `aside` element and then *sneak* it inside the outer `grid` container - check out the demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article,
aside {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "section aside";
}

section {
  grid-area: section;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "subhead subhead" "content empty";
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 80vw auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

section article:first-child {
  grid-area: header;
}

section article:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: subhead;
}

section article:last-child {
  grid-area: content;
}

section:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  grid-area: empty;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 20vw;
  align-self: flex-end;
  position:relative;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <article>Article title</article>
    <article>Article sub-heading</article>
    <article>Article content</article>
  </section>
  <aside>Aside</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually worked around the issue in a different way, but from what I can tell, your method may have worked as well - snippet runs successfully.  When I have a moment I'll review in more depth and compare to mine to see if I might swap.  Off the bat, I have a feeling the fixed heading height will be an issue for my employer... Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid rgb(233,171,88);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(233,171,88,.5);
  padding: 10px;
  color: #d9480f;
}.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two { 
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.three {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  min-height:200px;
}
.four {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  min-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Also check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yxbckzcq/)

And for more details please visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Thanks for this however, my requirement (stated in the question) is that your class "one", "two", and "three" are all part of the same element - <article>.

Comment: You can use `<article class="wrapper">` instead of  `<div class="wrapper">`

Comment: But then the <aside> (your class "four") is part of <article>, which is not correct...  :/

Comment: Also `GRID CSS` have a very less browser support. So it's better to go with some other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by simply floating all the cells, as long as the article doesn't float - https://jsfiddle.net/yxbckzcq/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <article>
    <div style="float:left;width:100%" class="one">One</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100%" class="two">Two</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:70%" class="three">Three</div>
  </article>
 <div  style="float:left;width:30%" class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My preference was to use CSS Grid, but from my research so far it does seem that it's not possible, and that I'd need to use an approach similar to this.